# Possible ways to induce norm from inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $ S $ be a normed vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$, say, for simplicity) with norm $ \lVert\cdot\rVert$.

Can this norm be induced from inner product only through $\lVert \cdot \rVert = \sqrt{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}$ ?

As to prove the if part of "A norm is induced by inner product iff the norm satisfies parallelogram equality", $\lVert \cdot \rVert = \sqrt{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}$ is used.

Comment: Wouldn't any other norm you define be equivalent to the standard induced norm?

Comment: This is the Jordan-von Neumann Theorem.  Here's a proof in the complex case: https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m113w10/public_html/jordan-vneumann-thm.pdf .

Comment: @KyleW I didn't get you. If you mean like L_3 norm to be equivalent to the standard induced norm, then it's not true.

Comment: In a finite dimensional inner product space, any two norms you induce from the inner product will be equivalent.

Comment: Your sentence beginning "As to prove .." is unintelligible. Please clarify it: saying "can be induced" rather than "is induced" makes a significant difference to the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this depends entirely on what you mean by a norm being induced by an inner product. The way this expression is usually used, *the* norm induced by the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is *by definition* the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert = \sqrt{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}$. If you were to use the expression more loosely, you might for instance say that $\lVert \cdot \rVert = 2\sqrt{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}$ is also "a norm induced by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$". You wouldn't be following standard usage, but it would be understandable. In any case, this definitional question is the only one at issue here; as far as your question seems to imply that there is anything to prove here, I believe this is mistaken. In the theorem you quote at the end of the question, the above standard definition of a norm being induced by an inner product is presupposed.

Answer (score 6):

In an inner product space
$$
\langle v, w \rangle = \frac{1}{2}(\|v + w\|^2 -\|v\|^2 - \|w\|^2)
$$
So the norm determines the inner product. The norm on a normed vector space is induced by an inner product iff the function $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ defined by the above formula satisfies the axioms for an inner product. The Jordan-von Neumann theorem says that this is so iff $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies the parallelogram identity:
$$
\|v + w\|^2 + \|v - w\|^2 = 2(\|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2)
$$
Normed vector spaces with this property are called Euclidean.

Comment: Thanks to the person who kindly corrected the typos in the second equation above. Unfortunately, your edit was rejected by the moderators. A comment would probably have been a better way to raise the issue.